# Catalina system and data volumes with "find"

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, apfs

I sometimes find it useful to be able to search my entire hard disk with the "find" command, but I want to exclude all volumes on external drives. I have a script that I use in lieu of the "find" command to exclude external volumes.

Since Catalina, the script is still searching in some duplicate locations due to the read-only system volume and the data volume. So I have had to tweak the script to prevent this.

Ideally I would like a way to specify "exclude external volumes but include the main hard drive". This could be accomplished using the -prune subcommand, if it was allowed to afterward override it. For example something like "find \ ./Volumes -prune --overrideprune ./Volumes/Macintosh\ HD". My made up --overrideprune subcommand would mean "prune all Volumes as previously specified, but then add back the main hard drive volume directory.

Because I have not figured out how to do this, I have to explicitly prune for each external volume. And when the volume layout changes, then I have to update the script.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command Danile C. Sobral
# using special syntax to avoid traversing. 
# However, logic is refactored (will post to that page so see what the reaction is)

echo ============================
echo find - from cwd, omitting external volumes
date
echo Enter sudo password if requested
sudo find . -not \( \
-path ./System/Volumes/Data -prune -o \
-path ./Volumes/Backup1 -prune -o \
-path ./Volumes/Backup2 -prune -o \
-path ./Volumes/FLASH -prune -o \
-path ./Volumes/SuperDuper\ Catalina -prune -o \
-path ./Volumes/SuperDuper\ Catalina\ -\ Data -prune -o \
-path ./Volumes/SuperDuper\ Spare -prune -o \
-path ./Volumes/SuperDuper\ Spare\ -\ Data -prune -o \
-path ./Volumes/Time\ Machine\ 1 -prune -o \
-path ./Volumes/Time\ Machine\ 2 -prune -o \
-path ./Volumes/Time\ Machine\ MBP\ 1 -prune -o \
-path ./Volumes/Time\ Machine\ MBP\ 2 -prune -o \
-path ./Volumes/userland -prune \
\) -name "$1" -print 2>/dev/null
date
echo ============================
```

Please note: the above script works, but requires maintenance when volumes change and to compensate for Catalina read-only and data volumes. So I am looking for a replacement for the find command in the above that would be generic and appear something like the following:

```
sudo find . -not \( \
-path ./Volumes -prune -o \
-path --overrideprune ./Volumes/Macintosh\ HD \
\) -name "$1" -print 2>/dev/null
```

By the way, the page referenced in the second comment line of the first script above is has great discussion of the use of the prune subcommand.

Comment: Have you tried `mdfind`?

Comment: I had a brief notion that the `fstype local` option would help, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: This is a "*good question*". I've tried several things without success, but I've never had a situation where I was trying to `find` over the entire `Macintosh HD`. I do get odd results in some `find` searches, which makes me wonder if Apple's rather convoluted file system has rendered `find` as incapable of doing its job? It seems [`find` is 2011 vintage](https://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-207.11.1/find/), and there have been many changes since then. GPLv3 was a "reason" for not updating `bash`, but `find` is under BSD license. I guess Apple needs a better excuse? :)